# PostgreSQL Merge 2 queries to 1 with save ordering execution

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I need to merge two queries to single:

First:

```
UPDATE instances 
SET enabled = FALSE 
WHERE last_order_at NOTNULL AND auto_disable_h NOTNULL AND status != 'NEW' 
AND last_order_at <= ago_excl_weekend(auto_disable_h) 
RETURNING 1;
```

Second:

```
UPDATE settings s 
SET archived = TRUE, archived_at = current_timestamp 
FROM instances i 
WHERE s.archived = FALSE AND i.enabled = FALSE AND i.id = s.instance_id 
RETURNING 1
```

`RETURNING 1` it's ORM caprice any query should return something.

The main problem is how to save ordering this of queries. First `instances` update prepare status state for condition from second query `i.enabled = FALSE`. These queries ask to merge with a join but how I should merging it and not lost order?

Tables:

```
-- Instance
CREATE TABLE instances
(
    id               BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    enabled          BOOLEAN      NOT NULL,
    status           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_order_at    TIMESTAMP,
    auto_disable_h   INT
);

-- Instance settings
CREATE TABLE settings
(
    id          BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    archived    BOOLEAN        NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    archived_at TIMESTAMP,
    instance_id BIGINT         NOT NULL REFERENCES instances (id),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a cascading `update`: that is, the second update should take the rows updated in the first one as an input.

In Postgres, you can write this as:

```
with i as (
    update instances 
    set enabled = false 
    where 
        auto_disable_h is not null 
        and status != 'new' 
        and last_order_at <= ago_excl_weekend(auto_disable_h) 
    returning id
)
update settings s 
set archived = true, archived_at = current_timestamp 
from i 
where s.archived = false and i.id = s.instance_id 
returning 1
```

Side notes:

- `<col> notnull` is not valid SQL; I changed that to `<col> is not null`
- in the first query, there is no need to explictly ensure that `last_order_at` is not `null`; the other inequality condition on this column eliminateas `null` values already